# Error Creating relationship in SSAS Tabular

Tags: sql, ssas, relationship, tabular

We are having a very frustrating problem with SSAS.  we are trying to create a fairly simple Tabular model  have had no problem with a few dimensions and a single fact table.  when we recently added a new dimension table, and a second fact table we can not get it to stop telling us that

```
The relationship cannot be created because each column contains duplicate values.
```

we have deleted and reimported these tables many times.  at times we can attach the Dim table to an existing fact without problem, which tells me that the key is unique, but then it errors when attaching to a second fact.  at other times it just errors right away.

The key and Foreign Key values are `Int` in the database.  and we have examined the data many times, creating stripped down tables with just a few columns, validating that a

```
Select Distinct ID from Table
```

type query returns the same number of rows as a wide open one.

At this point it looks like we simply have a bug in SSAS Tab.  I cant see a good reason for this to not work.

any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hello, I am having exactly the same issue... I couldn't figure out the root cause for this... the funniest part is that my model has already a lot of facts that share a lot of dimensions... today I had to add two new dimensions, and there boom... the error message you get keeps popping up when I try to link a second fact to the new dimension... have you found anything about this somewhere else ?

Comment: I have just solved the problem... but i am even more confused will post the answer below

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, the way I solved is to create the relationship in reverse order meaning: from the 1 to many. This will solve the issue, and the relationship's direction will indeed be from the many to the 1
I do not have any explanation for this...

Answer (score 0):

sometimes SSAS cannot detect that your column is unique so you should do that. you can click on your primary key column and get properties and choose true on the unique property and after that create your relationship

[image]